# app_offline.htm throwing HTTP 500 errors on production box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, app-offline.htm

I have created an **app_offline.htm** file for an ASP.NET MVC2 application running on IIS7 / Win2008 64-bit, and ensured that it's over 512 bytes (it's 2KB right now). On my dev box running Visual Studio 2010, it works like a charm, but when I put it on the production box, all I get is the generic HTTP 500 error saying "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

What's especially strange is that I don't get anything logged in the application event log, nor does ELMAH pick anything up. I've disabled custom errors, put FormsAuthentication location exceptions for the file, ensured I'm not referencing any other files (images, etc.), but nothing fixes it.

I've read every post on SO and Googled for hours and can't figure this out.  Any ideas what might be wrong? I'm pulling my hair out here...

Comment: Is there more information in the server's event log?

Comment: No, that's the strange thing - there is nothing thrown on the server at all, not in the App event log or the System event log.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site from localhost? that sometimes shows more detail. also have tried firefox and/or switching off friendly http error messages in IE so it shows you the actual error.

Comment: Not from localhost at the server, but I'll try that. I've tried in Firefox and Chrome but I don't get anything but a single line of simple text.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE:**

Do you have this in your web.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime waitChangeNotification="300" maxWaitChangeNotification="300"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> But there’s one more catch.
>
> ASP.NET will unload the application as
>   soon as the web.config is changed, but
>   it won’t actually reload it and apply
>   the “waitChange…” settings until a
>   request is made. So you could still
>   drop the app_offline.htm and
>   web.config in, and if the first requst
>   occurs while a dll is only half
>   copied, the exception will occur. To
>   add insult to injury, the exception
>   will persist until you replace the
>   temporary web.config or the total
>   duration of your “waitChange…” time
>   expires!
>
> To get around this final hurdle, you’d
>   need to make a request to the
>   application after uploading the
>   temporary web.config, but before you
>   start deploying the application files.
>   The complete process is as follows:
>
> 1. Add app_offline.htm
> 2. Replace application’s web.config with a temporary web.config (as above)
> 3. Request any ASP.NET resource on the site so the new
>      waitChangeNotification gets “applied”*
> 4. Make any file system changes necessary (deploy bin dlls, other site
>      files)
> 5. Replace temporary web.config with the original application
>      web.config
> 6. Delete app_offline.htm
>
> *You may dispute what happens in step 2-3, since ASP.NET shuts down the
>   application after step 1. Indeed, it
>   does not appear from my event viewer
>   that the web.config change is
>   registered or “applied” as a result of
>   either step 2 or 3, but nevertheless
>   the updated waitChangeNotification
>   settings do get applied after step 3.

[More app_offline.htm woes](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/more-app_offline-htm-woes/)

[App_offline.htm gotchas with ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: Yeah, that's in the web.config. This problem is still present, but I'm not ready to throw in the towel yet. There has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: Here are the updated links from above:
http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/ 
http://blog.kurtschindler.net/more-app_offline-htm-woes/

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution that works 100% for our deploys, so I thought I'd share it.

This solution adds a **customErrors** section to the **web.config**. This will catch any unhandled exceptions. It redirects to the **App_Offline.htm**, which refreshes until the application comes back online. So the user gets a nice loader that goes away when the application becomes available.

I hope this is helpful :)

**Batch File**

```
copy "C:\www\_App_Offline.htm" "C:\www\App_Offline.htm"
copy /y "C:\www\App_Offline.config" "C:\www\Web.config"

Rem do deploy/publish actions

Rem Note: Our publish replaces/restores the Web.config. You should do that here.
del "C:\www\App_Offline.htm"
```

**App_Offline.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime waitChangeNotification="100" maxWaitChangeNotification="100"/>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="App_Offline.htm" mode="On">
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**_App_Offline.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Application Offline</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .facebook_blockG { background-color: none; border: 3px solid #D6D6D6; float: left; height: 40px; margin-left: 7px; width: 24px; opacity: 0; -moz-animation-name: bounceG; -moz-animation-duration: 1.3s; -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -moz-animation-direction: linear; -moz-transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-animation-name: bounceG; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -webkit-animation-direction: linear; -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); -ms-animation-name: bounceG; -ms-animation-duration: 1.3s; -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -ms-animation-direction: linear; -ms-transform: scale(0.7); -o-animation-name: bounceG; -o-animation-duration: 1.3s; -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -o-animation-direction: linear; -o-transform: scale(0.7); animation-name: bounceG; animation-duration: 1.3s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-direction: linear; transform: scale(0.7); }
        #blockG_1 { -moz-animation-delay: 0.39s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.39s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.39s; -o-animation-delay: 0.39s; animation-delay: 0.39s; }
        #blockG_2 { -moz-animation-delay: 0.52s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.52s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.52s; -o-animation-delay: 0.52s; animation-delay: 0.52s; }
        #blockG_3 { -moz-animation-delay: 0.65s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.65s; -o-animation-delay: 0.65s; animation-delay: 0.65s; }

        @-moz-keyframes bounceG {
            0% { -moz-transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 0.6; }

            100% { -moz-transform: scale(0.7); opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes bounceG {
            0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 0.6; }

            100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes bounceG {
            0% { -ms-transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 0.6; }

            100% { -ms-transform: scale(0.7); opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes bounceG {
            0% { -o-transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 0.6; }

            100% { -o-transform: scale(0.7); opacity: 0; }
        }

        @keyframes bounceG {
            0% { transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 0.6; }

            100% { transform: scale(0.7); opacity: 0; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="overlay" class="trans">
        <div id="overlay-inner" class="trans login">
            <h1 style="line-height:1em; font-size:30pt">Application Offline</h1>
            <h2 style="line-height:1em; width:70%; margin:auto">application is offline for maintenance</h2>
            <div style="width: 128px; margin:40px auto">
                <div id="blockG_1" class="facebook_blockG">
                </div>
                <div id="blockG_2" class="facebook_blockG">
                </div>
                <div id="blockG_3" class="facebook_blockG">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            var loc = getParameterByName('aspxerrorpath');
            loc = (loc) ? window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + loc : window.location.href;
            window.location.assign(loc);
        }, 1500);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very helpful, I adapted this for our site and it works great. Thank you!